# Composer update or require error array_key()

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

coming here for an error when i try to do a composer update or a composer require in my symfony project.

It always return : `array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given`

Didn't know why, and it since i do a cache clear on composer (cause i got an other error before, a 400 Bad request error on composer require).

Thanks for your help.

After doing composer update -vvv, i can see this message many times :

`Skipping download: The 'http://packagist.org/p/provider-2020-01%2434fef7bea0581958875b62f3f1fae710400212a6a3d187c167fba3d903f3b012.json' URL could not be accessed: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request`

Edit : It seems my proxies are not taken by composer, and i didn't found any configuration file where we can call them. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

After `composer update` or the likes, it runs a Symfony command. Which generally trigger any app error when in dev mode, this is most likely where the source of your problem is.

The error message should refer to a file/line to where something (and what) is going wrong.

If you don't have a stacktrace and can't find where it is you can also use verbose mode `composer update -vvv` to get full debug info.

Comment: Thanks, so it's still a URL could not be accessed: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad request on all ligne he tried to update. 
I have configured my proxy as well but it seems to still didn't work well, any other idea for?